# How to make BeautifulSoup output more consistent

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to print number of home listings on Airbnb page:

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/Girona--Hiszpania/homes?place_id=ChIJRRrTHsPNuhIRQMqjIeD6AAM&query=Girona%2C%20Hiszpania&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=b5bnciXv'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

listings = soup.select('._f21qs6')

print(len(listings))
```

The print output should be "18", this is how many listings are on this page.

However, the output is inconsistent. Sometimes I indeed get "18", but other times it is "0".

Is there anything I can improve in this code to make the output more consistent?

EDIT: I have refactored the code to make the inconsistency in output evident:

```
import requests, bs4

def get_listings():
    url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/Girona--Hiszpania/homes?place_id=ChIJRRrTHsPNuhIRQMqjIeD6AAM&query=Girona%2C%20Hiszpania&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=b5bnciXv'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    listings = soup.select('._f21qs6')
    return listings

def check_if_all_listings_downloaded():
    number_of_listings = len(get_listings())
    print("Current number of listings: " + str(number_of_listings))
    while number_of_listings != 18:
        print("Too few listings: " + str(number_of_listings))
        number_of_listings = len(get_listings())
    print("All fine! The number of listings is: " + str(number_of_listings))

check_if_all_listings_downloaded()
```

Example output of this refactored code is:

```
Current number of listings: 0
Too few listings: 0
Too few listings: 0
Too few listings: 16
All fine! The number of listings is: 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the parser here.`bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')`
use html parser rather than lxml...I tried your code with html parser and it seems to be consistent.. I am not sure why lxml is showing inconsistency  [Difference Between Parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)    Refer this link to know the difference between parsers

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, sadly specifying the parser didn't help, the output is still inconsistent, sometimes 18, and sometimes 16 or 0...